# Batch index updates?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, indexing

I'm writing several hundred or potentially several thousand rows into a set of tables at a time, each of which is *heavily* indexed both internally and via indexed views.

Generally, the inserts are occurring where the rows inserted will be adjacent in the index.

I expect these inserts to be expensive, but they are *really slow*. I think part of the performance issue is that the indexes are being updated with each individual INSERT.

Is there a way to tell SQL Server to hold off on updating the indexes until I am finished with my batch of inserts so the index trees will only need to be updated once?

These are executed as separate statements due to needing to show the user a progress bar during save and log any individual issues, but are all coming from the same connection in C#. I can place them in a transaction if needed, though I'd prefer not to.

Comment: "several thousand rows" is not very many. Should be practically instant... Of course we have no idea what hardware you have...

Comment: I'm *inserting* potentially several thousand rows at the end of the table, but the table has a few million rows. The speed issue is definitely in updating the indexes. Hardware is pretty current, and the database performs well other during this particular task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are paying the cost of adding those rows to the index one way or another.  Not updating the index during the insert would cause an issue with accuracy of concurrent statements - any query on that table that used any of the indexes would not "see" the new rows!

If speed is of the essence, and downtime after the insert isn't a major concern, you can:

- Disable non-clustered indexes on the target table
- Inert
- Rebuild non-clustered indexes

You probably should clarify some more about your table:

- How wide is the table?
- How many indexes?
- How wide are the indexes?

If you have 20 indexes and each index has 5 fields, you are really updating 100 extra fields per row which can get expensive quickly.

Comment: Yes, I know I'll pay eventually, but I think the number of individual edits to each index is what is killing me. The rows inserted are almost always row-adjacent in the various indexes, so I was hoping there was a way to, perhaps, use a transaction and reduce the number of individual edits to those index pages.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at with the "individual edits" part.  If you add 10 rows to a table, you need to have 10 updates to each index no matter how you spin it.

Comment: Yes, there are 10 updates to the index, but with ten index page lock/write/unlock operations. I'm hoping that since the changes should be impacting relatively few index pages, that I can defer the index updates so they occur as a minimum number of locks and writes.

Comment: Someone else may come along and correct me, but I don't think the locking is going to be much of a bottleneck.  The time saved for locking/writing once instead of once per row is minimal next to the time spent actually writing the data to the pages of the index, which is happening one way or another.